# How can I write a window function using something like row_number to increment only on discrete values?

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

Say I want to do something like:

```
select 
     my_date,
     row_number() over(partition by my_date order by my_date asc)
from
     my_table
```

I want the row numbers to come out as:

```
2018-10-01,1
2018-10-01,1
2018-10-02,2
2018-10-03,3
```

Not quite sure how to do this. With the current window function, it does:

```
2018-10-01,1
2018-10-01,2
2018-10-02,1
2018-10-03,1
```

Comment: If you partition by mydate, the count will restart for every new date. I believe the answer by @a_horse_with_no_name is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`

```
select my_date,
       dense_rank() over(order by my_date asc)
from my_table
```